# Statusbar and layout issues with UIImagePickerController after rotation

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, autorotate, uistatusbar

tl;dr: User interface layout is broken when rotating the iPad while taking a photo, if the app displays a status bar.

I've got an app that shows a status bar that should take photos through a `UIImagePickerController`.

I'm running this on an iPad 3, iOS 6 with Xcode 4.51

The first problem I noticed was that if I didn't hide the statusbar via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

before the call to

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then the `UIImagePickerController` would not be shown correctly on the screen. The space for the status bar would still be reserved (but no time or battery information etc. shown) with the result that the controls at the lower end of the screen would be partly off-screen.

So, I added the line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

before presenting the `UIImagePickerController` and the first problem was solved.

Now comes the second problem (caused by the solution to the first problem). When I bring up the `UIImagePickerController`, rotate the iPad and close it (via "cancel" or "use", doesn't matter), the handler (either `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` or  `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` gets called, in which I show the status bar again, via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

The problem is now that the status bar is shown in fact, but the rest of the app seems to be unaware that it is on the screen again. (The UIToolbar that I have on my "MainViewController" is partly hidden behind the status bar.) The interesting thing is, if I rotate the iPad to any other orientation all is displayed correctly again after the animation finishes.

Can anybody give me any tips on how to solve this problem? (Currently my best work around would be to leave the status bar hidden after the first time somebody took a photo, but that's kind of sub-optimal). Maybe there is a better solution to the first problem, or maybe a method to solve both issues.

Further information: After rotating the iPad to landscape while `UIImagePickerController` was active, this is the frame of my MainViewController's view frame: {{0, 0}, {1024, 768}} (i.e. in the case where there is the problem). When I have the iPad in landscape orientation all the time, this is the MainViewController's view frame after the `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed: {{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} (This is the case where there is no problem.)

Thanks in advance for your attention and effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the same issue on iPhone when displaying an image picker that takes an image from the camera. The solution I found was to make a call to show the statusbar when the view that popped up the image picker will re-appear. Eg.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's already part of the solution. Now the app looks correct after I leave the image picker. But there is a new problem now: when I rotate the device afterwards the status bar jumps to the correct position (top) but the rest of my app doesn't rotate and remains sideways... Did you solve that problem too?

Comment: My app is portrait only so I didn't come across this problem. If you find a solution though post it back here for others to see.